# How can I stop Python from finishing while running a C# DLL program (API) with user input?

Tags: python, c#, api, input, dll

I've been browsing and couldn't find an answer to my question. Hopefully it's not too complicated because it might be multilayered... and I'm not an expert in Python(beginner) or C#(beginner-intermediate)!

What I'm trying to do is to use python and use a C# DLL which is an API that run another program. However, there are events in the DLL that asks for user input in the terminal. When I type something in the terminal, python ends because the python script finishes and the API calls gets interrupted and stops.

Here is a breakdown of what steps I took:

1. Use a C# DLL in my Python script via pythonnet and clr

```
import pythonnet
import clr
clr.AddReference("C:\path\to\dll\test.dll")
```

2. Call a function from the DLL in Python

```
from Namespace1 import Class1
my_obj = FunctionFromTestDLL()
```

3. C# DLL calls and runs an external program - and this is an API call

```
void FunctionFromTestDLL(out string userData)
{
    MyAPI_ = new MyAPI.CompanyAPI();
}
```

4. Python script finishes and the C# call was disrupted. I fixed this by adding an input at the end of the script:

```
input("Don't close this until Program finishes running!\n")
```

5. However, one of the DLL functions have an event handler, and that triggers a few times. However this event needs user input.

```
void UserInputEvent(out string userData)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("What is your data? \n");
    userData = System.Console.ReadLine();
}
```

6. I type my user input "cake" and the python script finishes and the C# call was disrupted again.

I want to be able to send user inputs back to C# because the external program will take those inputs for further processing.

I tried to look into importing subprocess but it doesn't seem like the right answer.

Edit: Thanks for the link. I'm not familiar with MCVE so hopefully this edit is better @CristiFati

Comment: Call the function in a synchronous manner. Or if the function only starts some flow, there should also be one that queries that flow status. But all this is pure speculation. Please edit your question to be a *MCVE*: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).